# Formatting Hard Drive before installing Ubuntu & some

Tags: system-installation

I'm thinking of installing Ubuntu (for the first time) on my internal hard drive to run as a primary OS on my Acer Aspire. Want to format my hard drive altogether and either run Ubuntu solely or alongside freshly reinstalled Windows 7 (it's that time again - windows is all bugged down).

Got a few questions though.

**1.** I've read that on installation of Ubuntu we get an option of 
"use entire disk" - will this erase all the info on my hard drive (like formatting in DOS)?

**2.** My Windows installation files are pre-loaded on my hard drive. If i decide to go back to Windows (can't think of a reason why, but just in case :) will i still have Windows installation files if i use the option "use entire disk" installation for Ubuntu or is it safer to reinstall Windows (even though i won't be using it) and then run Ubuntu along side it?

**3.** I'm currently using 64 bit Windows 7. Should i install 64 bit Ubuntu?

I'm planning to use the latest 11.10 version of Ubuntu.

Thanks for all your answers in advance.

Vidrom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I've read that on installation of Ubuntu we get an option of "use entire disk" - will this erase all the info on my hard drive (like
>   formatting in DOS)?

Yes.

> My Windows installation files are pre-loaded on my hard drive. If i decide to go back to Windows (can't think of a reason why, but just in
>   case :) will i still have Windows installation files if i use the
>   option "use entire disk" installation for Ubuntu or is it safer to
>   reinstall Windows (even though i won't be using it) and then run
>   Ubuntu along side it?

According to me, it is safer to keep Windows for now. You can remove later, once you gain confidence.
If you use "use entire disk", it will format whole drive, then you will not be able to reinstall Windows from preserved installation on the hard disk.

> I'm currently using 64 bit Windows 7. Should i install 64 bit Ubuntu?

Doesn't matter. You can use either of them.

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes, to the best of my knowledge (I almost never use these options), using the entire disk will, effectively, use the entire disk. This will entail re-partitioning the disk, so the data will probably be lost. Note however that the partitioner Ubuntu uses does not, in fact, wipe all the data off the drive (like Windows does, iirc) but just modifies the partition table.
2. I *think* Windows keeps those in a separate partition. In any case, using the entire disk will wipe that off and Windows will thus be forever lost (not that it'd be such a bad thing)! You will need to use a custom partition layout (there are many different possibilities, up to you) and keep that "hidden" Windows partition intact. Or you can re-install Windows first and install Ubuntu alongside if you feel safer that way.
3. As with Windows 64-bit, you have to be aware that some applications might not work, or be available, in 64-bit Linux. However, I find Linux generally has fewer problems of that kind (mostly because as software in open-source, it can easily be recompiled for 64-bit architectures), so I recommend 64-bit installs if your hardware supports it (here, it does).

Comment: Wow, Thanks for such a quick replies guys!!! I thought of doing exactly what you've both suggested, just wanted to get a second opinion from more experienced users. Ubuntu - here i come!!!!!!!!